# How do I automate the process of pulling the latest code and restarting a service on git push?

Tags: git, gitlab, cicd

I have an application (Logstash) running on a Linux VM and the settings for it are on a GitLab repo. What I want is for the VM to pull the latest version of the settings file and restart the service when I push an update to the repo.

What is the easiest way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

There's no "easiest" way per se, there's the better way for you.
I'd recommend using a configuration management tool like Chef or Puppet (for a pull model) for which there's already resources to configure and handle logstash restarts.

That said logstash is able to watch its config file and reload it itself, quoting elastic.co documentation:

> Starting with Logstash 2.3, you can set Logstash to detect and reload configuration changes automatically.
>
> To enable automatic config reloading, start Logstash with the `--config.reload.automatic` (or `-r`) command-line option specified. For example:
>
> ```
> bin/logstash –f apache.config --config.reload.automatic
> ```

So you may just set a crontab to `git pull` your repository periodically and have logstash reload itself.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest `jenkins` for this as it can easily integrate wit `github`, `gitlab` or any other SCM. Jenkins jobs can be setup such that the build runs whenever you push a commit to the `gitlab` repo. In the job, you can mention to update the logstash config on the linux VM and then reload/restart your service.

Here are some articles which can help you in proceeding further.

http://fourkitchens.com/blog/article/trigger-jenkins-builds-pushing-github/

https://oncomputingwell.princeton.edu/2018/01/triggering-a-jenkins-build-every-time-changes-are-pushed-to-a-git-branch-on-github/

NOTE: 
If you want to setup this just for a single node, You can also create a very simple script which should pull from github, say every 5 mins, and if the changes are there, it can update logstash config and simply restart the logstash.